# lost connection with the positive one. Exit (sigter) Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

I have a curious problem with Flutter, it turns out that I am developing an application for Windows and nowhere, jump a message on the purification console that says "Lost Connection to Device. Exited (Sigterm)". Then purification connection is lost but the application is open. I go to the task administrator, I close it and when I am going to purify again the message Link: Fatal Error LNK1168: Cannot Open. This mistake is annoying since I have to purify the application and I can't make a hot-reload.
Am I the only one that happens to you? I appreciate your aid

I have tried Flutter Clean, Flutter Pub Get, I manually eliminated the BUILD folder, restarted the equipment.
Something to comment is that I use the desktop_multi_window bookstore and when I compile I launch an error, close the application and since then I have followed that problem. I have read in forums that has to do with the antivirus. I do not know how true it is since it did not happen before.